# xml parsing in iOS show null

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing

I must read an XML file and read the id attribute within the XML file, but the dictionary out null. The xml is:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <root>
<event id="2"></event>
 </root>
```

My code:

```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

  NSLog(@"elementName is %@", elementName);
  // elementName is root
  NSLog(@"AttributeDict is %@", attributeDict);
  //AttributeDict is { } why?
  //I must extract "id" in event but does not entry

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"event"]){ 

    NSLog(@" %@", elementName);

}

}
```

Comment: You don't have any data in the event check your xml which you have pasted in the question

Comment: yes but the event has no data in it "<event id="2">...</event>" as suggested by @ernaidu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"event"])
    {
        NSLog(@" %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id");
    }

}
```

The element `root` don't have any attributes, that's why the `attributeDict` displays as empty, when `elementName` is root.